# Using Logic Laws to prove $p \leftrightarrow q \equiv (p\lor q)\to(p \land q)$

Tags: propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove that

> $p \leftrightarrow q \equiv (p\lor q)\to(p \land q)$

and am really lost in the steps to solve this.

So far I have:

> $p \leftrightarrow q \equiv (p\to q)\land(q\to p) \qquad$|equivalence
>    $p \leftrightarrow q\equiv (\neg p\lor q)\land(\neg q\lor p) \qquad$|implication

and I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

edit:

Thanks to lord farin i now have

> ≡ (~p ∨ q) ∧ (q → p)  Implication Law
>   ≡ (q → p) ∧ (~p ∨ q)  Commutative Law
>   ≡ (q → p ∧ ~p ) ∨ (q → p ∧ q) Distributive Law
>   ≡ (~p ∧ q → p) ∨ (q ∧ q → p) Commutative Law

but i am unsure of how to get there still.

Comment: i forgot to add that the first step

p↔q≡(p→q)∧(q→p)p↔q≡(p→q)∧(q→p)|equivalence

is mandatory and i am to work from there to prove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to expand only one of the two implications materially at first:

$$\begin{align*}
(p\to q)\land(q \to p) &\equiv (\neg p \lor q)\land (q\to p)\\
&\equiv \underbrace{(\neg p \land q \to p)}_{\downarrow} \lor \underbrace{(q \land q\to p)}_\downarrow& & \text{distribution}\\
&\equiv \underbrace{(\neg p \land \neg q) \hspace{1.5em} \lor\quad(p \land q)}_\downarrow\\
&\equiv \hspace{2em}(p \lor q) \to (p \land q)
\end{align*}$$

I'll leave it up to you to take care of the transitions represented by the arrows.

---

**Additional details**: For the first two, you can rewrite the conditionals, then use distribution of the $\land$. For e.g. the first, this will leave $(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land p)$, the second term of which is always false. Thus the whole expression is equivalent to $\neg p \land \neg q$.

A similar approach works for $q \land q \to p$.

Comment: im really sorry but can you please expand on the first arrow transitions? Ive spent a few hours to no avail on how to get it there.

Comment: @DamienLim See edit.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
(p\lor q)\to(p \land q) & \equiv (p\lor q)'\lor(p \land q)\\
 & \equiv (p'\land q')\lor(p \land q)\\
 & \equiv (p'\lor(p \land q))\land (q'\lor(p \land q))\\
 & \equiv ((p'\lor p) \land (p'\lor q))\land ((q'\lor p) \land (q'\lor q))\\
 & \equiv (T \land (p'\lor q))\land ((q'\lor p) \land T)\\
 & \equiv (p'\lor q)\land (q'\lor p)\\
 & \equiv (p\rightarrow q)\land (q\rightarrow p)\\
 & \equiv p \leftrightarrow q 
\end{align}

Comment: To downvoter: could you please explain what is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$ **equivalence consists of two implications in opposite directions**

$(2)$ **it is enough to negate just one of the two implications in order to negate the equivalence**

$(3)$ **truth can imply no lie, therefore, to negate an implication, the second predicate must be negated, while the first stays unchanged**

Having in mind these simple facts, no other tool is required.
$$\neg(\neg P)\equiv P$$
$$\neg(\neg (p\iff q))\equiv p\iff q$$
$$\neg((p\wedge \neg q)\vee(\neg p\wedge q))\equiv p\iff q$$
Neutral for disjunction:
$$\neg(((p\wedge \neg q)\vee (q\wedge \neg q))\vee((\neg p\wedge q)\vee (p \wedge \neg p)))$$
Distribution:
$$\neg(((p\vee q)\wedge\neg q)\vee ((p \vee q)\wedge \neg p))\equiv\neg((p\vee q)\wedge(\neg p \vee \neg q))\equiv \neg((p\vee q)\wedge \neg(p\wedge q))$$
Finally:
$$\neg(\neg((p\vee q)\implies(p\wedge q)))\equiv(p\vee q)\implies(p\wedge q)$$

Hope it helps. So, you can see how, using 'primitive' elementary tools, we can transform more complicated statements.

Answer (score -2):

You could write equivalence as $(p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$, which gives us, using commutation and implication law, the result you desire.